# Can I increase the range of a howitzer by using more propellant?

Tags: pressure, pressure-vessel, combustion

The muzzle velocity of a firearm can, all else equal, be increased by lengthening the barrel of the weapon which can theoretically be extended up to the point that friction and air resistance would overcome the benefit of pressure buildup in the barrel.

I think that the range of a howitzer be increased simply by adding more explosive propellant. Why is this not used? I would think that this would be a straightforward way to increase the gun's effective range. Any ideas?

Comment: A fixed chamber length...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the limitations to this approach.

First of all a *howitzer* is specifically designed for relatively short-range use, by using a very steep (in some cases, almost vertical) launch angle which allows the howitzer projectile to be lofted high up above trees, buildings, and even hilltops and then strike the intended target by falling almost vertically downward upon it.

Because of this, adding range to the howitzer does not increase its utility. For hitting more distant targets, a *gun* (i.e., cannon) is used instead, which is fired on a flatter trajectory.